# Spacing of colons in math equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The standard notation for the semidirect of a group G by a group H is `$G \rtimes H$` or `$G\ltimes H$` depending on whether H is acting on G or G is acting on H. However, occasionally, people write the semidirect product using a colon. I've been typesetting this as `$G:H$` but I find this produces too much space on either side of the colon. I alternatively tried typesetting this as `$G\text:H$` but then the spacing is too tight. The spacing in superscripts/subscripts seems to more what I have in mind. For instance `$\Phi^{G:H}$` seems to produce better spacing.

Is there an alternative option for using a colon in a math environment? Or is it possible to introduce my own colon and control the spacing myself?

I know there is `\colon` but this only reduces the spacing on one side and is more appropriate for function definitions, such as `$f\colon G \to H$`.

Comment: By default, `:` is of type `mathrel`. This means that in text style and display style, `5mu` of whitespace ("thickspace") is inserted on either side. In script style and scriptscript style, though, no whitespace is inserted -- that's what you're observing in `$\Phi^{G:H}$`. If you like this look, you should be OK with `${G{:}H}$` as well. (Encasing a math item in curly braces converts it to type math-ordinary; such "atoms" do not get surrounded by whitespace.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I take it there's no chance that readers of your document will become confused between three potential meanings of `:` (a) relational operator, (b) `\colon` (with asymmetric spacing), and (c) symbol for "semidirect of a group". (If there is such a chance, you better stick with `\ltimes` and/or `\rtimes` for "semidirect of a group", right?)

If there's no chance for such confusion, you may want to set up a custom macro called, say, `\sd`, as follows:

```
\newcommand\sd{\mkern1.5mu{:}\mkern1.5mu} % "semidirect"
```

`1.5mu` is half of a thin-space. If that's not tight enough for your taste, try replacing the two instances of `1.5mu` with `1mu`.

Here's a comparison of various possible spacing choices:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\sd{\mkern1.5mu{:}\mkern1.5mu} % "semidirect"

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{\ttfamily}l}
G\mathrel{:}H  & \textbackslash mathrel  (5mu) (default)\\
G\mathbin{:}H  & \textbackslash mathbin  (4mu) \\
G\,{:}\,H      & 3mu symmetric \\
G\colon H      & \textbackslash colon, 0mu/3mu asymmetric) \\
G\sd H         & 1.5mu symmetric, \textbackslash sd\\ 
G\mathord{:}H  & \textbackslash mathord (0mu)\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll just add this in case it's of interest to anyone else. If you want the spacing to change in superscripts/subscripts then one can replace `\mkern1.5mu` with `\mathchoice{\mkern1.5mu}{\mkern1.5mu}{}{}`. This will mean in superscripts and subscripts there will be no additional spacing, just as with the normal usage of the colon.